# How to make Where clause dynamic in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

After logging into ones account and clicking 'Accept' button the system should insert a sequence of numbers in mysql table under "otp" column for validation purpose. The problem here is I want to make it dynamic in the WHERE clause. It should recognize and insert otp according to user ids itself.
Following is the code.

```
if(isset($_POST['generate']))
{
    $num = (rand(111111, 999999));

    file_get_contents("somelink");

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET otp='".$num."' WHERE id = 21");
    $qry_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    mysqli_close($con);

    header("location: otp.php");
}
```

Comment: where the user id come from? `$_GET` var?, `$_POST` var?

Comment: looks like you're needing to use cookies. But your question is not clear.

Comment: @Accountantم id is a Primary key which is assigned to users automatically whenever they registered.

Comment: @Setop When I am giving id=21 it updates that row. And if another user register, It will assign him id=22 so it is like static and I need to change id every time to update the table.

Comment: you should be getting an error for this

Comment: there's also another way to do this. So, any of the answers solved it? You didn't accept one or commented under an answer, so it seems to be anybody's ballgame.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Those are not the solutions to my question... It is just another way to do same thing..

Comment: @SKhan what do you mean? This `$query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET otp='".$num."' WHERE id = 21");
    $qry_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);` errors out. If you don't believe me, use `mysqli_error($con)` on it. Edit; You'll see a "1".

Comment: @SKhan so what's not working then? You never said that, nor have you commented under any of the answers provided to you. You're leaving everyone in the dark with your silence. See those and comment under them. Otherwise, this post has gone stale; I'm out.

Comment: Dear All,
Simple way to do this is to create another table and insert your otp details there.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use var concatenated  with your sql .. this behavior can allow sql injection so you should use prepare  bind_param and execute

and assuming you have in  var the valure for match the id you coould use this var for  param too

```
$con = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET opt = ? WHERE id = ?");
$con->bind_param('ii', $num, $id);

$num  = (rand(111111, 999999));
$id = 21;
$con->execute();

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using [RAND()](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_sqlserver_rand.asp) in SQL?

```
UPDATE users SET otp = RAND() WHERE id = 21
```